# $index overlapping with $parent.$index

Tags: javascript, templates, loops, angularjs, scope

I have nested ng-repeats which are conflicting with each other

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input ng-if="!item.choices" ng-model=data["item"+$index] type="text"/>

    <div ng-repeat="choice in item.choices">
       <input ng-model=data["item"+$parent.$index] type="radio" name={{item.name}}/>
    </div>
</div>
```

The indexes inside of the second loop are conflicting with the first. For example, if there are 2 radio buttons, they conflict with the first and second input's, despite the fact that they should have different indexes. Changing the radio button value changes the first and second text field input values. What is the issue?

Comment: can you provide an example ? I don't understand what is not working.

Comment: Yes. For example, image that I had 4 inputs, the first two being text inputs generated by the outer loop, and the forth and fifth being radio buttons generated in the inner loop. What I want is for them to be represented as data.item0,data.item1,data.item2,data.item3. Instead I am getting 2 sets of what appears to be data.item0, data.item1. In short, the inner loop is acting as if I am using it's own index, as opposed to the outer index.